# How to position yAxes labels in chartJS

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I want to align the y-axis tick labels *above* the ticks in chartJS.

Here's what I've got so far:

[image: what I've got so far]

I want the tick labels `0M`, `20M`, and `40M` above the tick labels. Something like this:

[image: I want this]

Here's my chart config:

```
new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data,
    options: {
      ...
      scales: {
        xAxes: [{ ... }],
        yAxes: [{
          stacked: true,
          position: 'right',
          gridLines: {
            drawBorder: false
          },
          ticks: {
            maxTicksLimit: 3
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  })
```

I'm not able to find any option in the chart options to do such a thing. Please help

Comment: try to create a new scale type and override `getPixelForTick` method

Comment: @Rhea sorry I'm new to ChartJS. Can you post some code?

Comment: Can you add the code or a JSFiddle with the code you are currently using to create the chart?

Comment: @TotZam OK, I've added the relevant code for my chart's config

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by adding an `animation` to the `options` config:

```
options: {
    animation: {
        duration: 1,
        onComplete: function() {
            var controller = this.chart.controller;
            var chart = controller.chart;
            var yAxis = controller.scales['y-axis-0'];

            yAxis.ticks.forEach(function(value, index) {
                var xOffset = chart.width - 40;
                var yOffset = ((chart.height - 60) / 2 * index) + 15;
                ctx.fillText(value + 'M', xOffset, yOffset);
            });   
        }
    }
}
```

JSFiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/m5tnkr4n/1/

You may need to adjust the hardcoded numbers in the `xOffset` and `yOffset`. These numbers will depend on the height and width of your chart, as well as what features you are displaying the in the canvas area. For example, if you remove the `xAxes` tick labels, you many need to decrease the `-60` since that will make the chart slightly shorter.  `/ 2` works since you set the `maxTicksLimit` to 3.

Comment: Thanks for the code and it's explanation! That's exactly what I wanted :)

Comment: when hover on chart (show tooltip) then yaxes is hidden!

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the tick position with `mirror`, `labelOffset` and `padding`

```js
scales: {
   yAxesA: {
      id: 'yAxisA',
      type: 'linear',
      position: 'left',      
      ticks: {
         display: true,
         mirror: true,
         labelOffset: -5,
         padding: 5
      }
   }
}
```