# Chart js: how can I align the legend and the title

Tags: charts, chart.js

[image]

I want to align the orders to the left and the legends to center center.
I've tried doing

```
title:{
      display:true,
      fontSize:18,
      text: "Products",
      titleAlign:'left'
    }
```

but `textalign` doesn't seem to work for me nor the `horizontal`

Answer (score 4):

Check the Chart.js docs, there is no options like titleAlign, see: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/title.html.
It should be in the future, there is an pull request for that:
https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/pull/5866 .

There is an option to do that, you should not display chart title and add your own.
Here is example how I've done that

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h5>{{ title }}</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
         <canvas id="my-chart" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also put the code below at the end of chart script and then hide your legend in your chartjs options. This creates a ul element in the div that you can manipulate with css using the class and/or the id for greater control.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="js-legend" class="chart-legend"></div>
    </body>
    <script>

        /*-- Your chartjs code here --*/

        document.getElementById('js-legend').innerHTML = barChart.generateLegend();

    </script>
</html>
```