# Why yAxis axisLabel align left is resulting position label inside the bar in Apache ECharts

Tags: javascript, charts, echarts

The expetacion result is like this post: [How to set labels align left in Horizontal Bar using chart.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52862436/how-to-set-labels-align-left-in-horizontal-bar-using-chart-js) but it's implemented in Apache ECharts

Any idea?

```js
var chartDom = document.getElementById('main');
var myChart = echarts.init(chartDom);

var options = {
  color: ["#3398DB"],
  tooltip: {
    trigger: "axis",
    axisPointer: {
      type: "shadow"
    }
  },
  grid: {},
  xAxis: [{
    type: "value",
  }],
  yAxis: [{
    type: "category",
    axisLabel: {
      align: 'left',
      margin: 40
    },
    data: ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]
  }],
  series: [{
    name: "直接访问",
    type: "bar",
    barWidth: "60%",
    data: [10, 52, 200, 334, 390, 330, 220]
  }]
};

myChart.setOption(options);
```

```css
#main {
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
<p>Test</p>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@5.2.1/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `margin` for axisLabel, to make the labels visible. Updated your code snippet