# How to align ticks label in chartJS 3.x?

Tags: chart.js

is possible with chartJS chenge the align position of tick labels for scaleY and for scaleX?
In the image attached i want 300,150,60, 0 on top of the grid line and 9:56 aligned on the right of the first tick.

[image]

I try to modify the code in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43677197/how-to-position-yaxes-labels-in-chartjs) answer, but without success.

Answer (score 0):

After some research i adapted the method showned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43677197/how-to-position-yaxes-labels-in-chartjs) to works with ChartJS 3.x:

```
plugins: [{
afterDraw: function (c) {
    var yScale = c.scales['y'];
    yScale.ticks.forEach(function (o, i) {
        // top tick label indent
        var yT_O = yScale.getPixelForTick(i) - 9;
        // left tick label indent
        var xT_O = c.width - 35;

        c.ctx.fillStyle = "#707070"
        c.ctx.fillText(o.label, xT_O, yT_O);
    });
}
```

}]

Actually i'm not sure this is the best plugin event where do that.
I also had to put *"display: false"* on the ticks options in order to hide the originals tick labels.